# Difference between View.INVISIBLE and value of android:invisible

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm new on Android development, so I'm developing an simple application that hides a textview pressing some button, so in the java code in the method for the OnClick event for the button I set the textview as invisible, I used:

```
textView.setVisibility(1);
```

because 1 is the value for "invisible" described in the [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility), but it does not work, so after I used

```
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and it works, so When is the "1" value used? and Why is View.INVISIBLE = 4 instead of 1 as the android reference says?

In the android reference I can see that the value Invisible for attribute android:visibility is defined as 1

Comment: The reference you posted a link to clearly shows that `View.INVISIBLE` is `4`.

Comment: Maybe he is wondering why there is a inconsistency between R.attr and the constant.

Comment: Exactly, I can't figure it out why android:visibility is 1 and View.INVISIBLE is 4

Comment: yeah, maybe it's some inconsistency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, I checked the Android source code (frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java)

```
case com.android.internal.R.styleable.View_visibility:
    final int visibility = a.getInt(attr, 0);
    if (visibility != 0) {
          viewFlagValues |= VISIBILITY_FLAGS[visibility]; //here is the key to your question
          viewFlagMasks |= VISIBILITY_MASK;
    }
    break;
```

Here is the content of VISIBILITY_FLAGS:

```
private static final int[] VISIBILITY_FLAGS = {VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE};
```

The value of the array elements are actually the value shown in [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)

```
/**
     * This view is visible.
     * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
     * android:visibility}.
     */
    public static final int VISIBLE = 0x00000000;

    /**
     * This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
     * Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
     * android:visibility}.
     */
    public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;

    /**
     * This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
     * purposes. Use with {@link #setVisibility} and <a href="#attr_android:visibility">{@code
     * android:visibility}.
     */
    public static final int GONE = 0x00000008;
```

So even if you use the android:invisible in the manifest file, Android framework will finally call setVisibility(...) with the value 4.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's good to know the code, I can't find where that "1" for the main.xml is used for, in the .xml you can't set 1 as value, you have to set "invisible", and neither in the activity....

Answer (score 3):

Both are difference.
According to [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)

```
textView.setVisibility(1);
```

is same with

```
textView.setVisibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
```

If you want to hide the view, use :

```
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Or

```
textView.setVisibility(4);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but why in the android reference the value "invisible" for android:visibility is defined as 1?