# applying setLayoutParams on a button programmatically causes the whole layout to get mixed and abnormal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/insertButtonVIEW"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="insert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButtonVIEW"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="remove" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sometimes, depending on a situaiton, I am hiding removeButtonVIEW using the method `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
When that happens, I want to my insertButtonVIEW to take the whole width of the screen (when the two are present, each one takes 50% of the screen).

Since this might or might not happen, I am doing these changes programmatically.

I tried the following methd which worked, however, it is causing for all the interface to go jumbo mumbo, as everything's location on the screen is getting mixed.

```
modifyButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Any hints ?

UPDATE 1 after applying the answer : 
I am using the following code to set the button to invisible.

```
Bundle extras;
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String answer = extras.getString("answer");

if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")
{
  insertButton.setEnabled(true);
  insertButton.setText("INSERT");
  removeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else
{
 //whatever
}
```

Comment: Use `setVisibility(View.GONE);`. That should do the trick.

Comment: @Android-Developer did so, it is not resizing to the whole screen, just the 2nd button disappears, and the first button stays the same size, which is half the screen.

Comment: Are you setting the layout params programmatically too?

Comment: @Android-Developer no. just the width, actually I am applying the sole answer provided below.

Comment: can you please give an example when are you hiding the remove button, because I just implement the given idea above in another `onClickListener` and it's working.

Comment: @Android-Developer please check my updated answer, I inserted the code there. pretty straightforward tho.

Comment: Where is that code placed? In `onCreate`  or some other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// I Have modify your code now try this one and you don't required set LayoutParams ().

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/insertButtonVIEW"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="insert" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeButtonVIEW"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="remove" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")
{
  insertButton.setEnabled(true);
  insertButton.setText("INSERT");
  removeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
 //whatever
}
```

Comment: works. should have used View.GONE instead of View.Invisible. to know more about the difference, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928717/difference-between-view-invisible-and-value-of-androidinvisible

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

****Remove this ****

```
modifyButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**And set**

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
```

**in both button**

Comment: @birahZalavadia, doing so, removes the 2nd button, but the first button now occupies the half of the screen as it used to occupy before hiding the 2nd button.